# Iterating over lines in a file python

Tags: python

I have seen these two ways to process a file:

```
file = open("file.txt")
for line in file:
    #do something

file = open("file.txt")
contents = file.read()
for line in contents:
    # do something
```

I know that in the first case, the file will act like a list, so the `for` loop iterates over the file as if it were a list. What exactly happens in the second case, where we read the file and then iterate over the `contents`? What are the consequences of taking each approach, and how should I choose between them?

Comment: would be more accurate to say the `file` will act as a lazy `generator` in first sample. The second one will read the store the file content in memory for read.

Comment: Both are same, as far as I know. The best way to find out is, __print type(content)s__and __print type(file)__ Then we can be sure the types, where list or string

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the first one you are iterating over the file, line by line. In this scenario, the entire file data is not read into the memory at once; instead, only the current line is read into memory. This is useful for handling very large files, and good for robustness if you don't know if the file is going to be large or not.

In the second one, `file.read()` returns the complete file data as a string. When you are iterating over it, you are actually iterating over the file's data character by character. This reads the complete file data into memory.

Here's an example to show this behavior.

`a.txt` file contains

```
Hello
Bye
```

Code:

```
>>> f = open('a.txt','r')
>>> for l in f:
...     print(l)
...
Hello

Bye


>>> f = open('a.txt','r')
>>> r = f.read()
>>> print(repr(r))
'Hello\nBye'
>>> for c in r:
...     print(c)
...
H
e
l
l
o


B
y
e
```

Comment: Also the second reads the whole file in memory, whereas the first, one line per iteration. That said, the first is memory efficient, especially for big files.

Comment: @geompalik Thanks, I added that to my answer as well.

Answer (score 15):

The second case reads in the contents of the file into one big string. If you iterate over a string, you get each character in turn. If you want to get each line in turn, you can do this:

```
for line in contents.split('\n'):
     # do something
```

Or you can read in the contents as a list of lines using `readlines()` instead of `read()`.

```
with open('file.txt','r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
for line in lines:
    # do something
```