# How do I compare every line of the 1st text file to every line of the 2nd text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have 2 text files named f1 & f2 with 100k lines of names each. I want to compare the first line of f1 with every line of f2, then the second line of f1 with every line of f2, and so on. I already tried using nested for loop like code below but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong I can't seem to find? Please can someone tell me?

Thanks in advance.

**old.txt**

```
sourcreameggnest
saturnnixgreentea
saxophonedesertham
footballplumvirgo
soybeansthesting
cauliflowertornado
sourcreameggnest
saturnnixgreentea
```

**new.txt**

```
goldfishpebbleduck
saxophonedesertham
footballplumvirgo
abloomtheavengers
venisonflowersea
goodfellaswalker
saturnnixgreentea
```

**Code:**

```
 with open('old.txt', 'r') as f1, open('new.txt', 'r') as f2:
    
    for line1 in f1:
        print('Line 1:- ' + line1, end='')
        
        for line2 in f2:
            print('Line 2:- ' + line2, end='')
            
            if line1.strip() == line2:
                print("Inside comparison" + line1, end='')
```

Output:

```
Line 1:- goldfishpebbleduck
Line 2:- sourcreameggnest
Line 2:- saturnnixgreentea
Line 2:- saxophonedesertham
Line 2:- footballplumvirgo
Line 2:- soybeansthesting
Line 2:- cauliflowertornado
Line 2:- sourcreameggnest
Line 2:- saturnnixgreentea
Line 1:- saxophonedesertham
Line 1:- footballplumvirgo
Line 1:- abloomtheavengers
Line 1:- venisonflowersea
Line 1:- goodfellaswalker
Line 1:- saturnnixgreentea
```

Comment: What does "doesnt work" mean?

Comment: why are you `strip`ping one line but not the other? This could create a difference and avoid the match that you're after.

Comment: After the first `for line2 in f2:` loop, you've exhausted the iterator on the lines of the file, so the following such loops are empty. But as suggested in the first answer, you need a different approach, as you would need 10^10 comparisons this way...

Comment: How are you even looping over lines without actually reading the lines?

Comment: @JosipJuros Iterating on a file iterates on its lines, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671685/iterating-over-lines-in-a-file-python

Comment: @user1984 I am using strip in 1st text file only because the other file doesn't contain any empty lines.

Comment: But you're stripping the newline character even from non-empty lines and then there won't be a match even if the lines were the same.

Comment: Are the names unique?

Comment: @haxor789 no they have repeated names

Comment: @ThierryLathuille but reading one line per iteration using this for loop is more memory efficient than reading the whole file into memory. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the answers of @LukasNeugebauer and @Thierry Lathuille, here's what your code should look like:

```py
with open('old.txt', 'r') as f1, open('new.txt', 'r') as f2:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()
    lines2 = f2.readlines()
    for line1 in lines1:
        print('Line 1:- ' + line1, end='')
        if line1 in lines2:
            print("Inside comparison" + line1, end='')
```

If you are wondering, whether using `in` check is faster then iterating through the second list and comparing each value with `==`, I tested it. For both files containing 10,000 lines of random strings, it took ~2.8 seconds to process them fully with two loops and only ~0.8 using the `in` operator.

If your files are not bigger than a megabyte, I wouldn't really bother optimizing this, but otherwise you should really think about what you are actually comparing and what shortcuts can you use.

EDIT:
Some comments suggested making the second list of lines a `set`, (change 3rd line to `lines2 = set(f2.readlines())`) it would make the code much faster (the same example that I used above runs in only 4 miliseconds now, >200 times faster), but it may not actually solve the problem, since converting `list` to a `set` will remove all duplicates, so only use that if you are sure that you can discard duplicates.

Comment: thank you so much I forgot about this "in" method. My mistake

Comment: but this is memory efficient right? for like 100k above lines of text file as it won't load the text file in the memory instead compare line by line?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend testing if `lines1 in lines2` with lines2 being a list, as checking if some item is in a list is O(n), so this is still O(n^2). This is explicitely what `set`s are for, as suggested in user1984's answer, as the check is O(1) in this case.

Comment: The memory requirement is a few MB, which is nothing for any even not so modern computer. In your case, you should only care about the time, not space. And see my previous comment: make `lines2 = set(f2.readlines())`, not a list.

Comment: in for lists apparently has the time complexity of O(n) as can be seen here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity but the other problem is that there are apparently also duplicates where in would be sufficed to find the first occurrence (which is probably why it is faster), which might not solve the full problem.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the number of lines in the files I would entirely avoid the nested loop (`O(n^2)`) approach and load the lines of the second text file in a dictionary (if you care about the lines and/or the lines could be repeated), or in a set otherwise.

Then I would loop over the lines in the first file and check whether they are in the dictionary and act accordingly. This will use some extra space linear to the number of lines in the second file but reduce your time complexity to `O(n)` since dictionary lookups are constant.

As to your current solution's incorrectness, as pointed out by @Thierry Lathuille, the second iterator is exhausted after the first run of the outer loop, so it won't be checked for the remaining iterations. On mitigation is to read the lines of the file into a list where you can repeatedly loop over (`lines1 = f1.readlines(); lines2 = f2.readlines()`). Also, you use of `strip` is not correct if you intend to avoid whitespace lines. They will still be compared as empty strings with the added downside that stripping one line and not the other can create unwanted differences.

In any case, for such large numbers, an approach of quadratic time complexity is not feasible.

Comment: even when using strip on 2nd file. it doesn't work

Comment: Read my update and the comment by @Thierry Lathuille. The second iterator is exhausted after the first iteration of the outer loop. I've outline a mitigation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You already read to the end of the file after the first outer loop. Btw, I didn't know you could just loop over an opened file. Just store the lines first. Also I don't see why you would strip the '\n' only from one of the lines.

```
 with open('old.txt', 'r') as f1, open('new.txt', 'r') as f2:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()
    lines2 = f2.readlines()
    for line1 in lines1:
        print('Line 1:- ' + line1, end='')
        
        for line2 in lines2:
            print('Line 2:- ' + line2, end='')
            
            if line1 == line2:
                print("Inside comparison" + line1, end='')
```

Comment: Note that this approach, though correct for small files, doesn't scale well with the size of the data the OP manipulates, as it would require 10^10 comparisons.

Comment: You're right, I think the other answer by @user1984  is better, but the size of the  text files was added to the question later. Also it might still be educational as to why the approach didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with open('old.txt', 'r') as f1, open('new.txt', 'r') as f2:
    lines2 = f2.readlines()
    l2 = dict()
    
    # fill dictionary for line2 with each name and the lines it occurs
    for i in range(len(lines2)):
        l2[lines[i]] += [i]
    for line in f1.readlines():
        if line in l2:
            for j in l2[line]:
                print(line, j, ...)
```

Each of these 2 loops should have a complexity of O(n) and the lookup via in should be O(n).